# How to implement multiple instances of angular controller and allow other controllers to enquire state if each instance

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-service

**UPDATE 1**: I researched using angular service as suggested by @charlietfl. Based on my findings, I have rephrased the question, and clarified the details. See code parts and snapshot below to for more details.

I have defined a controller `app.controller('sig-pad', ...)` which will be used to control two instances of this controller which are the digital signatures for Appraiser and Supervisor. When the signature is signed and locked using password, then certain fields must be disabled, depending on which signature is locked; Appraiser or Supervisor. Such fields belong to different other controllers, and some of them might exist in the signature controller itself.

Say if the user signs the form and enters a password to lock the signature, then certain fields in the current page should be disabled. I was able to achieve this functionality on the fields inside the current controller `ng-controller="sig-pad"` using `<fieldset ng-disabled="isSigned()">`.

Originally, I was looking for a way to call the scope function `$scope.isSigned()` defined the signature controller from another controller. However, it seems this is not possible without using a service.

The page has a main controller `app.controller('mainController', ...)` on the body element `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController" ... >` which has access to all fields. Also, within the mainController, I have defined two instances of the `"sig-pad"` controller:

```
<div class="signature-wrapper" ng-controller="sig-pad as appraiserSignature">
                            <h4>Appraiser Signature</h4>...
```

and

```
<div class="signature-wrapper" ng-controller="sig-pad as supervisorSignature">
                            <h4>Supervisor Signature</h4>...
```

What I want to do now, is to define the password encryption, decryption and signature locking in a shared service named say `signatureLocking`, and reuse such service in the signature controllers (for Appraiser and Supervisor) and the main controller.

The final question now: Is it possible to create two instances of the same signature controller, use the shared service `signatureLocking`, and yet be able to identify which signature is locked: Appraiser or Supervisor? Then, be able to use the service from the main controller, and also the signature controllers to determine which signature is locked, so that I can disable the related fields accordingly.

Appreciate your feedback and recommendation.

```
<div class="signature-wrapper" ng-controller="sig-pad">
                            <h4>Appraiser Signature</h4>
                            <div id='signature-pad' class="m-signature-pad break" >
                                <div class="m-signature-pad--body" >
                                    <canvas redraw ng-signature-pad="signature" ng-hide="isSigned()"></canvas>
                                    <img ng-src="{{isSigned()?signature.toDataURL():''}}" ng-hide="!isSigned()">
                                    <input id="appraiser_signature" name="appraiser_signature" type="hidden" ng-value="singatureB64()"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
                                    <div class="description">Sign above</div>
                                    <!-- <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button> -->
                                    <!-- <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>  -->            
                                    <a class="btn clear" ng-click="clear()" ng-disabled="isSigned()">Clear</a>
                                    <a class="btn save" ng-click="sendData($event)" ng-disabled="isSigned()">Sign</a>
                                    <p ng-hide="true">Signature Result: {{signatureResult.result}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="break signature-details" >
                                <div class='signature-password'>
                                    <fieldset ng-disabled="false">
                                    <label for="app_password1">Appraiser Password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" id="app_password1" name="app_password1" ng-blur="appPassword1Exit('appraiser')" ng-model="password1"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="password" id="app_password2" name="app_password2" ng-model="password2" ng-hide="true"/>
                                </div>
                                <fieldset ng-disabled="isSigned()">                         
                                    <label for="id_appraiser_name">Name:</label><input id="id_appraiser_name" name="id_appraiser_name" type="text" ng-value="appraiser_name" ng-readonly="true"/>
                                    <br>
                                    <label for="appraiser_designation">Designation:</label>
                                        <select id="appraiser_designation" name="appraiser_designation">
                                              <option value=""></option>
                                              <option value="AACI">AACI</option>
                                              <option value="CANDIDATE">CANDIDATE</option>
                                              <option value="CRA">CRA</option>
                                              <option value="1">DAC</option>
                                              <option value="0">DAR</option>
                                              <option value="E.A.">E.A.</option>
                                              <option value="Other ...">Other ...</option>
                                        </select>
                                    <br>
                                    <label for="app_aic_member_number">Member #:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="app_aic_member_number" id="app_aic_member_number" ng-model="app_aic_member_number"/>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class='row' ng-controller="datePickerController">
                                        <!-- <input type="text" id="date_signed_appraiser" name="date_signed_appraiser"> -->
                                        <label for="date_signed_appraiser" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label vcenter">DATE SIGNED:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 input-group vcenter">
                                            <input id="date_signed_appraiser" name="date_signed_appraiser" type="text" 
                                                class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date_signed_appraiser" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='row' ng-controller="datePickerController">
                                        <label for="appraiser_date_inspection" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label vcenter">Date of Inspection:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 input-group vcenter">
                                            <input type="text" id="appraiser_date_inspection" name="appraiser_date_inspection"
                                                class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="date_signed_appraiser" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                 
                                    <br>
                                    <label for="appraiser_license_info">LICENSE INFO (where applicable):</label>
                                    <input id="appraiser_license_info" name="appraiser_license_info" type="text">
                                    <br>
                                    <label>NOTE: For this appraisal to be valid, an original or a password protected digital signature is required.</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                       </div>
```

The controller:

```
app.controller('sig-pad', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

$scope.appPassword1Exit = function (userRole) {
        //debugger;
        var pwd;
        if (!$scope.isSigned() && $scope.password1) {
            $scope.password2 = $rootScope.encrypt($scope.password1, $scope.singatureB64());
            alert('Form is now locked. Please remember the password \'' + $scope.password1 + '\'');
            $scope.password1 = null;
        } else if ($scope.password1 && $scope.isSigned()) {
            pwd = $rootScope.decrypt($scope.password2, $scope.singatureB64());
            console.log('decrypt pwd = ', pwd);
            if ($scope.password1 === pwd) {
                $scope.password1 = null;
                $scope.password2 = null;
                alert('Password is correct, the form will be unlocked.')
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, incorrect password.");
                $scope.password1 = null;
            }
        }
    $scope.isSigned = function () {
        if (!$scope.password2) {
            $scope.password2 = null;
        }
        return ($scope.password2 !== null);
    }
}]);
```

[image]

Comment: use a service to share data/methods across various parts of the app

Comment: I'm new to angular, appreciate you giving me example.

Comment: lots of tutorials on web regarding using services in angular. Probably worth going through a few of those. It's an important part of building angular apps

Comment: Thanks! I did some research, and it seems that I have a plan. Appreciate you taking another look at the updated post above, and if you have comments, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution, however, requires further improvements to optimize it. Following are the details:

Define the service: `signatureLocking`:

```
app.factory('signatureLocking', function($rootScope) {
    var theService = {};
    theService.signatureStatus = {};
    theService.userRoles = {};
    theService.userRoles.APPRAISER = 'appraiser';
    theService.userRoles.SUPERVISOR = 'supervisor';

    theService.password1Exit = function (userRole, $scope) {
        //debugger;
        var pwd;
        if (!$scope.isSigned() && $scope.password1) {
            $scope.password2 = theService.encrypt($scope.password1, $scope.singatureB64());
            alert('Form is now locked. Please remember the password \'' + $scope.password1 + '\'');
            $scope.password1 = null;
        } else if ($scope.password1 && $scope.isSigned()) {
            pwd = theService.decrypt($scope.password2, $scope.singatureB64());
            console.log('decrypt pwd = ', pwd);
            if ($scope.password1 === pwd) {
                $scope.password1 = null;
                $scope.password2 = null;
                alert('Password is correct, the form will be unlocked.')
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, incorrect password.");
                $scope.password1 = null;
            }
        }
        theService.signatureStatus[userRole] = $scope.isSigned;
        //console.log('Password1Exit - userRole = ', userRole);
    }


    theService.isAppraiserSigned = function () {
        var appraiser = theService.userRoles.APPRAISER;
        //debugger;
        if (theService.signatureStatus[appraiser] === undefined) {
            theService.signatureStatus[appraiser] = function (){ return false };
        }
        return theService.signatureStatus[appraiser]();
    }
    return theService;
})
```

Define the main controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$rootScope', 'signatureLocking', function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope, signatureLocking) {
    $scope.redrawCanvas = function() {
        //console.log('redrawCanvas');
        var triggerResize = function () {
            //console.log('inside trigger resize function');
            $scope.$broadcast('resize::resize')
        };
        $timeout(triggerResize, 250);
    }
    $scope.appraiser_name = "";
    $scope.isAppraiserSigned = signatureLocking.isAppraiserSigned;
}]);
```

Define the signature controller:

```
app.controller('sig-pad', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'signatureLocking', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, signatureLocking) {
    $scope.isSigned = function () {
        if (!$scope.password2) {
            $scope.password2 = null;
        }
        return ($scope.password2 !== null);
    }
    $scope.password1Exit = function (userRole) {
        signatureLocking.password1Exit(userRole, $scope);
        //debugger;
        console.log('password1Exit - Signature Status for role', userRole, signatureLocking.signatureStatus[userRole]());
    }
    $scope.isAppraiserSigned = signatureLocking.isAppraiserSigned;
}]);
```

The following HTML will trigger the password locking inside the signature controller:

```
<input type="password" id="app_password1" name="app_password1" ng-blur="password1Exit('appraiser')" ng-model="password1" ng-init="password1Exit('appraiser')"/>
```

Then simply, any controller that uses the service `signatureLocking` you can use the following HTML to get the status of say the appraiser signature and disable the fields accordingly

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="isAppraiserSigned()">                            
    <label for="id_appraiser_name">Name:</label><input id="id_appraiser_name" name="id_appraiser_name" type="text" ng-value="appraiser_name" ng-readonly="true"/>
    <br>
    <label for="app_aic_member_number">Member #:</label>
    <input type="text" name="app_aic_member_number" id="app_aic_member_number" ng-model="app_aic_member_number"/>
    ...
    ...
</fieldset>
```

The only issues I have with this solution are the following:

- The function to get the signature status is using a reference to the scope function defined in the signature controller
- I am passing the `$scope` variable from the controller to the service, is that OK?
- I used hard-coded value for the `userRole` parameter to trigger the password locking `ng-blur="password1Exit('appraiser')" ng-init="password1Exit('appraiser')"` for appraiser signature.

If you have any ideas to improve the solution, please let me know.